# extending default lib search path in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-11.04

How can i extend default lib search path in ubuntu(in a way that it is also persistent) ? no, I do **not** want export LD_LIBRARY_PATH based temporary solution, rather some way to extend the default lib search path ?

while google-ing, I cam across some info, that in ubuntu the default search path resides in */etc/ld.so.conf.d* , but editing libc.conf does not extended the default path.. so i think either i am doing it wrong, or something is missing...

the edited *libc.conf* looks like...

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib:/path_to_my_libraries/lib
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

create (as root) a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` containing, the new path. For example:

```
sudo echo "/path-to-your-libs/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/your.conf
```

after that run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

No need to change libc.conf.

Comment: Thanks! Note that just ".conf" file without name before extension doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

## Using `sudo`, without becoming `root`

This will create a `your.conf` file with a reference to `/path-to-your-libs/`:

```
$ echo '/path-to-your-libs/' |sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/your.conf
```

Do not forget to finish off with a **dynamic link library cache refresh:**

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```